# Camel CXF Rest SSL Handshake Error

Tags: ssl, client, cxf

We are using Camel CXF API for communicating with a secured server. This is 2-way SSL and we're talking to 3 different systems via Netscaler. 2 systems expose SOAP WS and we're able to establish 2-way SSL and exchange messages. The third system exposes REST APIs and is giving a very wierd problem at the SSL handshake. The error occurs when we Camel CXF in Fuse. A standalone Java Program running in its own JVM is able to successfully talk to the REST service.

We have enabled SSL debug flags and get the following errors in the logs.

```
Camel thread #0 - timer://foo, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
Camel thread #0 - timer://foo, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-11, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Camel thread #0 - timer://foo, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
Camel thread #0 - timer://foo, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Camel thread #0 - timer://foo, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
Camel thread #0 - timer://foo, called closeSocket()
```

Here's the configuration in Camel REST svc.

```
<!-- Key Manager & Trust Manager -->
<bean id="keyManagersBean" 
          class="test.IntegrationKeyManagerFactory" 
          factory-method="getKeyManager">
    <argument value="${security.keystorepassword}"/>
    <argument value="${security.keystorelocation}"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="trustManagersBean" 
      class="test.IntegrationKeyManagerFactory" 
      factory-method="getTrustManager">
    <argument value="${security.keystorepassword}"/>
    <argument value="${security.keystorelocation}"/>
</bean>

<!-- ==================== security configuration =================== -->
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http:tlsClientParameters>
        <sec:keyManagers ref="keyManagersBean"/>
        <sec:trustManagers ref="trustManagersBean"/>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
</http:conduit>

<!-- ====================== Camel Context & Routes ====================== -->
<camel:camelContext id="camel.test.context">
    <camel:route id="testRoute">
        <camel:from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=30s" />
        <camel:transform>
            <camel:constant>""</camel:constant>
        </camel:transform>
        <camel:removeHeaders pattern="CamelCxfMessage" />
        <camel:setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD">
            <camel:constant>GET</camel:constant>
        </camel:setHeader>
        <camel:to uri="cxfrs:{{protocol}}://{{host}}:{{port}}/{{context}}/getList" />
        <camel:log message="${body}"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem ? The exact same configuration works for communicating with SOAP WS via netscaler but not with REST WS via netscaler.

Comment: Made some progress on the issue where we found that for some reason the TLSClientParameters are null inside HTTP Conduit. Any reason  why this could be happending ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by switching over from camel cxf rsClient to using plain camel-http call. But think there's some issue with using HttpConduit with cxfrsClient.